# "Couldn't find package fail2ban"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, fail2ban

Ubuntu Server 9.10

Hi Guys,

I think this one is a simple one... I'm trying to install fail2ban and get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install fail2ban
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... 
Done E: Couldn't find package fail2ban
```

Which repositories do I need enabled in order to install it?

I'm presently have the following enabled in sources.list

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse
```

On a related note -- in the spirit of "teaching a man to fish", is there an easy way to find out where a package resides in general?

Thanks!

-M

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the **universe** component to any of the "main" (not security) sources.

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted universe
```

Packages not in the **main** component are marked as such with a red label after their name in the Ubuntu package database: http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/fail2ban

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Mikael.  How did you know that?

Comment: Mikey: One way to find out is search the official repos at http://packages.ubuntu.com/ ... if the package's not there, Google.

Comment: Edited my answer with the answer to the second question.

Comment: For anyone else not very familiar with Linux/apt - you make these changes to the /etc/apt/sources.list file

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest as an alternative DenyHosts: http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net